# How to create an active and dynamic bar graph from Mysql, php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

just to clarify the title, I want to make a bar graph which will read the data from the database table using MySql, and automatically changing the height to match the new data. The data is being fed to the database via an Arduino micro controller, so there is a continuous addition of data ever 0.5 seconds. I want the graph to detect the data and increase its height accordingly. Is there a way to do this without constantly refreshing the web page every 0.5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't refresh the whole page every .5 seconds.  There is a better way!

If you're not opposed to Jquery, use

```
$("#someDiv").load("somePage.PHP");
```

If no jquery, use:

```
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "somePage.PHP", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Now make a div to load the contents:

```
<div id="someDiv">
```

On the PHP page you load, you'll want to draw the chart. This method uses the bar chart from Chart.js: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart

See the link for more details.  Your code will look something like this:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: You'll want to wrap the ajax (whether you use jquery.load or pure javascript) in a function, and call that function as often as you want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX to make a call to a script every 0.5 seconds which will refresh only a portion of your page(the graph). Through AJAX you would be able to change the graph according to the data it fetches from a PHP(or otherwise) script with javascript.

Comment: thankyou and can you please point me to some material as a guide?

Comment: @AshwinRamesh Try out https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-ajax--ud110 I'm not sure if codeacademy covers AJAX. I'm sure you'll get there with a bit of google though.